# How can I install a program in Ubuntu with .install extension?

Tags: software-installation

It is a scientific software created by a researcher with .install extension. I am using the last version of Ubuntu. I have tried `./filename` as sudo without success.

Software: https://bitbucket.org/MDSINE/mdsine/downloads/

Installation instructions: Run the executable provided

If I execute chmod `+x mdsine_installer_linux_v1.3.install` I do not get anything. if I write `./mdsine_installer_linux_v1.3.install` I get this error:

```
Error: Download process failed - Unsupported protocol

. Check your internet connectivity, proxy server, firewall, and virus scanner settings and rerun the installer.
Installation failed.
```

Comment: It might help if You wrote what software. Also try to read the software's web site (if any) to see howto install it.

Comment: Thanks Soren A, I have provided the information you requested.

Comment: That file is an executable, so running it ought to work. Try `chmod +x mdsine_installer_linux_v1.3.install` to make sure it's executable. If still no joy, post the output of the terminal when you try to run the file.

Comment: If I execute chmod +x mdsine_installer_linux_v1.3.install I do not get anything. if I write ./mdsine_installer_linux_v1.3.install I get this error>
Error: Download process failed - Unsupported protocol

. Check your internet connectivity, proxy server, firewall, and virus scanner settings and rerun the installer.
Installation failed.

Comment: In the readme there is the following
`WARNING: There is an issue with the linux installer that occasionally will claim that you have an issue with your connection, and the installation will halt. It should take a few tries, but once it starts it should complete successfully.`

Comment: Hi, dariofac, yes, I am aware... but I never can make it work.

Comment: No output from `chmod...` means it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Your installer tries to access an HTTP address via internet. The server on internet, where your installer tries to go to, replies with `301 Moved Permanently`, which means that the file that installer tries to access has been moved and is no longer there.

The installer then quits as it does not find a file where it expects it.
Your installer wants the file `http://www.mathworks.com//pi_install_agent_pi_R2015b_glnxa64`, but it seems that it cannot handle `301 Moved Permanently` response, which redirects it to `https://www.mathworks.com/pi_install_agent_pi_R2015b_glnxa64`. Maybe installer cannot handle HTTPS at all?

Comment: That is quite insightful. Do I need to set up something in ubuntu to handle https? (with or without git)

Comment: I do not know what you can do. The installer program does what it does and I do not know if you can change it. You should contact the provider of the installer.